# Creating a vector of means of other groups outside of current row selection

Tags: r, shiny

Good afternoon all. I'm doing an analysis of latency for certain IP addresses by date. I have a vector that contains the concatenation of the IP address - Date as a character, called "ipdate" and a vector that has a mean of the "ipdate" column called "ipdateMean". This gives me the mean of a specific IP address for a selected day of the week.

What I'm trying to do is compare that against other IP addresses with the same date so that the user can see how their specific IP address selected is comparing against all the others. My thought was to create a separate vector called "ip_not_mean" that calculates the mean of all the other ip addresses for a certain date, but excludes, the mean of the ip addresses from the current row. See below

```
ipdate                         ipdateMean           ip_not_mean
123.32.56.78 - 2019.02.02         10                     30
123.45.67.34 - 2019.02.02         20                     26.6667
123.45.78.90 - 2019.02.02         30                     23.3333
123.45.78.56 - 2019.02.02         40                     20
```

I tried this but doesn't appear to be working.

```
dtCLIPKey$ip_not_mean <- mean(dtCLIPKey$ipdateMean[which(dtCLIPKey$ipdate != dtCLIPKey$ipdate)])
```

Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table` you can do the following:

```
setDT(dtCLIPKey)[, ip_not_mean := mean(dtCLIPKey[ipdate != .BY, ipdateMean]), by = ipdate]
```

Note that this only works if each value of `ipdate` is unique. If it isn't, I would create a count column that counts each row. Code for that is below:

```
setDT(dtCLIPKey)[, count := 1:.N][, ip_not_mean := mean(dtCLIPKey[count != .BY, ipdateMean]), by = count]
```

Afterwards, you can get rid of the `count` column by inputting:

```
dtCLIPKey$count = NULL
```